# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5

Tags: java, sql, exceção, prepared-statement

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em um treinamento porém mesmo seguindo os passos meu código retorna uma exceção que havia atribuído caso ocorresse.

Sei onde está o erro porém não consegui entender como corrigi-lo.

classe modelo

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Project {
    
    private int idProject;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Project(int idProject, String name, String description, Date createdAt, Date updatedAt) {
        this.idProject = idProject;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
    
    //Construtor para setar data inicial ao createdAt
    public Project(){    
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
   
    }
    
    public int getIdProject() {
        return idProject;
    }

    public void setIdProject(int idProject) {
        this.idProject = idProject;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

   
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project{" + "idProject=" + idProject + ", name=" + name + ", "
                + "description=" + description + ",createdAt=" + createdAt + ","
                + " updatedAt=" + updatedAt + '}';
    }

     
}
```

classe de controle

```
package controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.Project;
import util.ConnectionFactory;

public class ProjectController {
    public void save(Project project){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO project("
                + "name,"
                + "description,"
                + "createdAt,"
                + "updatedAt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        
        try{
            //inicia a conexão
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            //prepara a query
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            //insere valores ao atributos 
            statement.setString(1, project.getName());
            statement.setString(2, project.getDescription());
            statement.setDate(3,new Date(project.getCreatedAt().getTime()));
            statement.setDate(4,new Date(project.getUpdatedAt().getTime()));
            //Executa a query
            statement.execute();
        
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao salvar o projeto",ex);
        }finally{
            ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, statement);
        }
    }
    
    public void update(Project project){
        String sql = "UPDATE project SET"
                + "name = ?,"
                + "description = ?,"
                + "createdAt = ?,"
                + "updatedAt = ?,"
                + "WHERE idProject = ?";
        
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        
        try{
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1,project.getName());
            statement.setString(2, project.getDescription());
            statement.setDate(4, new Date(project.getCreatedAt().getTime()));
            statement.setDate(5, new Date(project.getUpdatedAt().getTime()));
            statement.execute();
        
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao alterar dados do projeto",ex);
        }finally{
            ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, statement);
        }
    }
    
    public void removeById( int idProject){
        String sql = "REMOVE FROM project WHERE idProject = ?";
        
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        
         try{
             connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
             statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             statement.setInt(1, idProject);
             statement.execute();
                     
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao deletar o projeto",ex);
        }finally{
            ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, statement);
        }
        
    }
    
    public List<Project> getAll(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM projects";
        
        List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        
         try{
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            
            while(resultSet.next()){
                
               Project project = new Project();
                
                project.setIdProject(resultSet.getInt("idProject"));
                project.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                project.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
                project.setCreatedAt(resultSet.getDate("createdAt"));
                project.setUpdatedAt(resultSet.getDate("updatedAt"));
                
                projects.add(project);
                                 
            }
        
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro mostrar lista de projetos",ex);
        }finally{
            ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, statement, resultSet);
        }
                
       return projects; 
    }
   
}
```

classe Main para teste

```
package TodoApp;

import controller.ProjectController;
import model.Project;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
      ProjectController projectController = new ProjectController();
      
      Project project = new Project();
      project.setName("Teste de controller 1");
      project.setDescription("Teste para verificar validade do controller");
      projectController.save(project);
    }
    
}
```

Erro que retorna

```
> Task :run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Erro ao salvar o projeto
at controller.ProjectController.save(ProjectController.java:38)
at TodoApp.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2560)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2536)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2462)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1300)
at controller.ProjectController.save(ProjectController.java:35)
... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não achei duplicata exata para sua situação, então vamos lá.

O erro diz que próximo à linha 35 da classe `ProjectController` não foi especificado valor para o parâmetro 5.

De fato, no seu `PreparedStatement` do método `save()` são vinculados quatro parâmetros mas o número de interrogações (`?`) é cinco. Ou seja, há uma interrogação a mais (ou um parâmetro a menos).

A solução é fazer com que o número de interrogações bata com o de parâmetros vinculados.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, segui a sua orientação e funcionou .